# ASP.NET Cannot get value from second modal input

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have two modal in a single .aspx file
and I call modal from code behind using

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Pop", "openImportModal();", true);
```

And due to I can't get input value from modal, so append the modal by using code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openImportModal() {
        $('[id*=ImportData]').modal('show');
    }
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
    function init() {
        var element = $('#ImportData').detach();
        $($("div")[0]).append(element);
    }

    function openAddPlayerModal() {
        $('[id*=AddPlayerForm]').modal('show');
    }
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init2, false);
    function init2() {
        var element2 = $('#AddPlayerForm').detach();
        $($("div")[0]).append(element2);
    }
</script>
```

When I use the first modal #ImportData , it can get input value from the modal, 
and when run to the second modal #AddPlayerForm , I can't get any input value from the modal...

Did anyone can help me to see how I can do for this ?
Many thanks !

Comment: Is the same way to call `openAddPlayerModal()` in the aspx.cs file with `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` method? Could you please provide more codes here? By the way, you can press `F12` key or insert `debugger;` js code to do debugging work by yourself.

Comment: Hi , yes, it's using the same way to call second modal (#AddPlayerModal()) from code behind

Comment: Which input values you want to get? Does the modal (#AddPlayerForm) is shown or not?

Comment: Yes, the Modal shown, and the input box for user to key in something, user will need to submit the form after data key-in, but system cannot get any value from the input box while submit, the same problem occured when doing first modal, hence I fix it by append the the element, and when call the second modal, this method is not worked for second modal

Comment: So, we may need more information to fix the issue. Could you please post the modal html and the getting values codes in code behind?